# How to tell Eclipse which Debug configuration to use as default?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I have created an Eclipse debug configuration, and saved it to a file. I'd like to share it with the team. However, when Eclipse project is imported, this configuration is not selected as the default one, so each user has to go to `Run/Debug Configurations...` and under the `Common` tab select `Shared file` and navigate to this file in order to use it.

How do I tell Eclipse which Debug configuration to use as default?

Are Debug/Run configrations ment to be shared at all?

Comment: If a launch configuration is shared, all users getting the shared `.launch` file will see the item in the right tree in the _Run > Run Configurations..._ dialog. They have not to go to the _Common_ tab. In addition, a launch configuration can also be added to the favorites menu (also in the _Common_ tab) to show it in Run/Debug button pull-down menu.

Comment: @howlger Could you add this as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a launch configuration is shared (stored as `*.launch` file in a project), all **users that get a local copy of the shared `*.launch` file** will **see the item in** the right tree in the ***Run > Run Configurations...*** dialog. They have not to go to the *Common* tab.

In addition, a launch configuration **can be added to** the **favorites menu** (also in the *Common* tab) **to show it in the Run/Debug button pull-down menu**.